# In R, select a group of rows and filter

Tags: r, select, rows

I have a data frame

> D

```
    col1 col2
1     2    8
2     2   10
3     2   10
4     2   19
5     5   16
6     7   15
7     5    8
8     5   10
9     5    1
10    5   19
11    1   16
12    1   15
```

I would like to select from col1 == 2, the rows where col2==8 and col2==19, at the same time, select from col1==5, the rows where col2 == 1 and col2==19. In other words, i want some like this

> D

```
    col1 col2
1     2    8
4     2   19
9     5    1
10    5   19
```

In my other case, i have a big data set with many rows and I would like to select many groups of the col1 and for each group, sequential codes of the col2. 
I would like too, some code working with character columns

Comment: What did you try by yourself?

Comment: functions like "select", "subset", "filter"... but i dont know the appropriate parameters

Comment: Have a look at the `data.table` package. THere are many many examples (including here on SO)

Comment: @mnel, I wonder what will be a good `data.table` solution for him. It seems he only wants two specific groups (which is easy to do), but he wants different rules per each group which will make `by` irrelevant in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you really want pairs of values with the `min` and the `max` within groups that are not necessarily located in contiguous rows. If I'm right then it would make more sense to create two result columns rather than arranging them in the manner you proposed:

```
> aggregate(D['col2'], D['col1'], function(x) c(min=min(x), max=max(x) ) )
  col1 col2.min col2.max
1    1       15       16
2    2        8       19
3    5        1       19
4    7       15       15
```

There are a variety of aggregation functions. I tried getting `tapply` and `sapply` to behave in an analogous manner and here you can see the results. (I needed to define a new function modeled on `setNames` to label the columns in the matrix returned by `sapply`):

```
setColNames <-  function (object = nm, nm) 
 { colnames(object) <- nm
    object
 }

> setColNames( sapply(unique(D[,'col1']), function(x) {z <- D[ D$col1 %in% x ,'col2'];  

c(min=min(z), max=max(z) ) }), unique(D[,'col1']) )
         2  5  7  1
    min  8  1 15 15
    max 19 19 15 16
```

And the `tapply` approach:

```
> tapply(D[,'col2'], D[,'col1'], function(x) c(min=min(x), max=max(x) ) )
$`1`
min max 
 15  16 

$`2`
min max 
  8  19 

$`5`
min max 
  1  19 

$`7`
min max 
 15  15
```

When you get a value like that retrurned by tapply above there is a very handy maneuver with do.call that can rbind them together:

```
val <-  tapply(D[,'col2'], D[,'col1'], function(x) c(min=min(x), max=max(x) ) )
> do.call(rbind, val)
  min max
1  15  16
2   8  19
5   1  19
7  15  15
```

Notice that the grouping values are now rownames rather than a column in its own right.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty straight forward to use `subset`.  Just need to get the right nesting of comparisons.

```
subset(D, (col1 == 2 & col2 %in% c(8,19)) | (col1 == 5 & col2 %in% c(1, 19)) )
```

Here we use `%in%` to check for more than one value at a time